# ruby on rails facebook authentication

Tags: ruby, facebook, ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth

I am new to Rails and I am creating app where I want login from facebook option. I have done it with the installation of `omniauth` gem.
And I am getting this error.

```
NameError: uninitialized constant OmniAuth
/home/ankit/face/config/initializers/omniauth.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ankit/face/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Which exactly gem you have? It should be 'omniauth-facebook'

Comment: I am using rails 4.1.0 and ruby 2.1.2 omniauth-facebook (1.6.0)